# Force function evaluation on declaration

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function `f[x_,y_,z_]:=Limit[g[x+eps,y,z],eps->0];` and I plot `f[x,y,z]` in the next step. Earlier, I used to evaluate the limit and copy the expression in the definition of `f`. I tried to make it all in one step. However, the evaluation of the Limit is done only when I try to plot `f`. As a result, every time I change around the variables and replot, the limit is evaluated all over again (it takes about a min to evaluate, so it becomes annoying). I tried evaluating the limit first, and then doing `f[x_,y_,z_]:=%`. But that doesn't work either. How do I get the function to evaluate the limit upon declaration?

Comment: what is the difference? I thought functions need to be defined using `:=`

Comment: No, functions can be defined with either `Set` (`=`) or `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  Generally you are correct to use `:=` for functions, but you will need to understand both of these to use Mathematica well.  It would be best to post a new question if you need help understanding them, in my opinion.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard @Yaroslav: Is it just me or *should* `SetDelayed[..., Evaluate[...]]` be a scoping construct as I described I thought it was in the comments below my answer? Is not the syntax hilighting (for `:=`) a bit misleading given its current behaviour?

Comment: @Simon The syntax highlighting breaks in quite a few contrived cases; it is by no means perfect.  I suspect that your construct is not common.  I'll have to think about the scoping behavior, but off hand it does not come as a surprise to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, @Yaroslav, @Simon, thanks for your answers. I never knew there was a difference. I've posted a new question on the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` and it would be cool if you guys explained it there. As I see it there isn't much space to write in comments.

Comment: @d'o-o'b see my updated answer to your separate question for an example of using `Set` for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Mr Wizard's solution is that you can also put the `Evaluate` in the function's definition:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[Limit[Multinomial[x, y, z], x->0]]

Plot3D[f[x, y, z], {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}]
```

You can compare the two versions with the one without an `Evaluate` by  `Timing` the `Plot`.

Comment: Simon, I did not recommend this because it only works on a toy example.  It seems to me that if one can use this construct, one can also simply omit `Evaluate` and use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.  There would be no need for the OP's `f[x_,y_,z_]:=Limit[g[x,y,z],x->0];` in that case.  No?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I always thought that the `f[x_] := Evaluate[ff[x]]` construct was better than a `f[x_] = ff[x]` because the syntax highlighting indicated local variables. But I just tested it, and they both fail the same way if you run `x=1; f[x_] := Evaluate[ff[x]]; g[x_] = ff[x]`... Anyway, I use this construction a lot.

Comment: Simon, I don't understand.  Why not use simply use, for example `f[x_] = g[x]` rather than `f[x_] := Evaluate[ g[x] ]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: No reason. I used to (before this morning) think that the variables were localised in the `SetDelayed`/`Evaluate` version, but after testing I see that it's not so. Although, I still do like the syntax highlighting that you don't get with `Set`.

Comment: @Simon: The confusing thing may be that the scoping constructs (`Set,SetDelayed, Block, With, Module, Function`) are also Mathematica expressions (heads) which (mostly) obey the standard evaluation rules. The fact that they are scoping constructs is reflected in the presence of the variable-binding stage, but that happens only when the built-in rules for them apply (which is "on the way up" in the evaluation sequence). Therefore, by wrapping Evaluate around their arguments (which is processed "on the way down"), you can manipulate their bindings, which is often a very useful capability.

Comment: Thanks @Leonid. I guess if you want to evaluate the RHS during the definition and keep the variables local, you can always `Block` the whole expression.

Answer (score 4):

The function you need is logically called `Evaluate` and you can use it within the `Plot` command.

Here is a contrived example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Limit[Multinomial[x, y, z], x -> 0]

Plot3D[ Evaluate[ f[x, y, z] ], {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}]
```

---

Addressing your follow-up question, perhaps all you seek is something like

```
ff = f[x, y, z]

Plot3D[ff, {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}]
```

or possibly merely

```
ClearAll[f, x, y, z]

f[x_, y_, z_] = Limit[Multinomial[x, y, z], x -> 0]

Plot3D[f[x, y, z], {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}]
```

It would be helpful if you would post a more complete version of your code.

Comment: But will that not force the function to be evaluated every time? The way it is now, I do not need it to be evaluated each time. One evaluation is sufficient.. after that, it's just fooling around with the plot variables.

Comment: I don't have trouble getting the function to evaluate... I just want it to be evaluated during declaration, instead of while plotting (as if I plot multiple times, it needs to be evaluated each time). In fact, Simon's solution worked well. I haven't tried yours yet, but it seems like it would do what I have been doing.

Comment: @d'o-o'b: Both solutions give basically the same behaviour for a single Plot command. For multiple plots, Mr.Wizard's solution would evaluate `f[x,y,z]` once for each plot - but that's nothing compared to once for every plot point as in your original code.

Comment: @Simon: ah, I didn't realize mine was evaluating once for each plot point!