# How to create a function directly from the output of Solve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I evaluate `Solve[f[x,y]==0,x]`, I get a bunch of solutions like:

`{{x -> something g[y]}, {x -> something else}}`, etc.

Now I want to convert each of those `x->somethings` into a function. Typically, my requirements are low, and my function `f[x]` is at the most a cubic, with straightforward solutions for `x`. So I've always just defined `g1[y_]:=something`, `g2[y_]:=...` etc, manually.

However, for a function that I have now, `Solve` outputs a complicated polynomial running 4 pages long, and there are 4 such solutions. I've tried reducing to simpler forms using `Simplify`, `Collect`, `Factor` etc, but it just seems irreducible.

Is there a way I can automatically assign them to functions? (It's extremely hard to scroll through pages and copy each one... and I have to look for where the next one begins!)

Something like: `{g1[y_], g2[y_], g3[y_]} = output of Solve`?

Comment: methink some x_ is wrong up there. Your `Solve[f[x]==0,x]` should not return things dependent on x, so assigning f[x_]:= to something without **x** seems pointless.

Comment: @belisarius, agreed. I hadn't written it out clearly. I've edited my post.

Comment: If the solutions are just messy cubics and quartics, then you can make `Solve` return a `Root` object by using the options `Cubics -> False` and `Quartics -> False`. This will look simpler and might even be faster and more accurate when evaluating.

Comment: @Simon: `Solve` doesn't take the options `Cubics/Quartics`, but `Reduce` works.

Comment: o'b: The option was added to `Solve` in version 8...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears Simon beat me to an answer (I am glad that StackOverflow gives me a pop-up to let me know!), therefore I will take a different approach.  You should know how to use the output of Solve directly, as quite a few times it will be convenient to do that.

Starting with

```
ClearAll[a, x, sols]

sols = Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]
```

Here are some things you can do.

---

### Find the solutions to `x` for `a == 7`

```
x /. sols /. a -> 7
```

---

### Plot the solutions

`Evaluate` is used here not out of necessity for basic function, but to allow the Plot function to style each solution separately

```
Plot[Evaluate[x /. sols], {a, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

---

### Define a new function of `a` for the second solution

Notice the use of `=` rather than `:=` here

```
g[a_] = x /. sols[[2]]
```

---

### Here is an alternative to Simon's method for defining functions for each solution

```
MapIndexed[(gg[#2[[1]]][a_] := #) &, x /. sols]
```

The function is then used with the syntax `gg[1][17]` to mean the first solution, and `a == 17`

```
Plot[gg[1][a], {a, 1, 4}]

gg[2] /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

---

These uses do generally require that `a` (in this example) remain unassigned.

Comment: The popup is handy! Given [this recent discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5318942/421225), I knew that you would pick up on my use of `SetDelayed[..., Evaluate[...]]` instead of just `Set[..., ...]`!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard @Simon What popup? I never get a pop-up, even if a whole army has posted before me.

Comment: @Sjoerd that is interesting.  If someone posts an answer while I am composing mine (typing in the answer box), I get an orange bar across the top of the screen, like the ones for "You've earned the Something badge..." (paraphrase).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps that NoScript is blocking something, but I granted permission to most of the services embedded here...

Comment: @Sjoerd if you ask about this on Meta, post a link.  I am curious.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll look for the pop-up for a couple of days and check whether I just missed it;  if not, I'll ask Meta.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, but how to use this method to make a function with `:=` and not `=` ? as that is really the common way (i.e. using `:=`). btw Maple has a special function for this sort of thing, to make a function out of an expression called `unapply()`, it is handy. Always wondered why Mathematica does not have one like that. Here is a link to `unapply()` for reference http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=unapply

Comment: @Nasser I shall review `unapply` but while I do does not the `MapIndexed` code near the bottom of the page do this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, had bit of hard time trying you MapIndexed, since `gg` is not defined, and was not sure how to make it up from your description next to it. Will be better if you make your example self contained by having the definition of `gg` in it as code. I think this will help us more, as this can be important method to use. Thanks

Comment: @Nasser, `gg` is the function that *gets defined* and then used in the examples that follow.  Please take another look at the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Ok, I see now. I did not fully understand your code. I was getting `{Null,Null}` after the `MapIndexed` call and I thought I am doing something wrong. Now I see that the call actually defines `gg`. Your code sometimes is too advanced for us normal users to follow, but now I see it. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser "too advanced" is generous of you, but in fact I don't do the best job explaining my code, though I am trying to improve.  I am glad it is working for you now.  I am still considering the function of `unapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that could be cleaned up

```
In[1]:= solns = Solve[x^2+a x+b==0, x]
Out[1]= {{x -> 1/2 (-a-Sqrt[a^2-4 b])}, {x -> 1/2 (-a+Sqrt[a^2-4 b])}}

In[2]:= Table[Symbol["g"<>ToString[i]][a_,b_] := Evaluate[x/.solns[[i]]],
              {i,Length[solns]}];

In[3]:= DownValues/@{g1,g2}
Out[3]= {{HoldPattern[g1[a_,b_]]:>1/2 (-a-Sqrt[a^2-4 b])},
         {HoldPattern[g2[a_,b_]]:>1/2 (-a+Sqrt[a^2-4 b])}}
```

Comment: General thinking here:  there has got to be a better way to do it than to leave all the `In[]` and `Out[]` tags as they are.  It is natural to copy and paste, and this breaks that.  I have been leaving out the `In[xx]:=` but preserving the `Out[xx]=` in my answers.  What do you think of putting dividing lines between input and output code?  Do you think that is understandable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'm not sure... it's a balance between making it clear on the screen/site and making it easy to transport to a notebook. I think I prefer for simple answers like this one, to leave the [Ins and Outs](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3520/) for the sake of clarity. For long, multiple line code, I only place the first `In[]` there (just like Mma) - then it can be easily copied. But it's all a matter of taste...

Comment: @Mr. Each time I post Mma code, I have to think how to do this same thing. And always get to " there has got to be a better way to do it", but never found it

Comment: @belisarius @Simon do you think a question / discussion about this is appropriate for Meta?

Comment: @Mr. I think narrow topics on obscure tags are not welcome in meta. I created a chat room. Let's see if it works. Not sure how to publicize its existence. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/628/mathematica-tag

Answer (score 1):

The following function will automatically convert the output of `Solve` to a list of functions (assuming `Solve` *finds* solutions of course):

```
solutionFunctions[expr_, var_] :=
  Check[Flatten @ Solve[expr, var], $Failed] /.
    (_ -> x_) :>
      Function[Evaluate[Union @ Cases[x, _Symbol?(!NumericQ[#]&), Infinity]], x]
```

Here is an example:

```
In[67]:= g = solutionFunctions[x^2+a x+1==0, x]
Out[67]= {Function[{a},1/2(-a-Sqrt[-4+a^2])],Function[{a},1/2(-a+Sqrt[-4+a^2])]}
```

The functions can be called individually:

```
In[68]:= g[[1]][1]
Out[68]= 1/2 (-1-I Sqrt[3])

In[69]:= g[[2]][1]
Out[69]= 1/2 (-1+I Sqrt[3])
```

Or, all of the functions can be called at once to return all solutions:

```
In[70]:= Through[g[1]]
Out[70]= {1/2 (-1-I Sqrt[3]),1/2 (-1+I Sqrt[3])}
```

The function will fail if `Solve` cannot find any solutions:

```
In[71]:= solutionFunctions[Log[x]==Sin[x],x]
During evaluation of In[71]:=
  Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
Out[71]= $Failed
```

Variables are automatically identified:

```
In[72]:= solutionFunctions[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]

Out[72]= { Function[{a, b, c}, (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)],
           Function[{a, b, c}, (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way:

```
In[1]:= f = Solve[x^2 + ax + 1 == 0, x]
Out[1]= {{x -> -Sqrt[-1 - ax]}, {x -> Sqrt[-1 - ax]}}

In[2]:= g1[y_] := x /. f[[1]] /. a -> y
        g2[y_] := x /. f[[2]] /. a -> y

In[4]:= g1[a]
        g2[a]

Out[4]= -Sqrt[-1 - ax]
Out[5]= Sqrt[-1 - ax]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really cool. Thanks. By converting Solve results into functions I could use Manipulate in a Plot. Something like

```
In[73]:= g = solutionFunctions[x^2 + a x + b == 0, x]
Out[73] = {Function[{a, b}, 1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])], 
  Function[{a, b}, 1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b])]}

In[74]:= Manipulate[Plot[g[[1]][a, b], {a, 0, 4}], {{b, 1}, 0, 10}]
```

And you get a plot where you can manipulate parameter b