# Mathematica: Extract numerical value when using Solve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, calling `Solve`, returns a list of rules, e.g.,

```
In[1]:= g = Solve[(x - 1) (x - 2) == 0, x]
Out[1]= {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}}
```

How can I extract the numerical values `1` or `2` from `g`?

I tried using `Part` e.g., `g[[1]]` but it returns `{x -> 1}` and not `1`.

Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a function directly from the output of Solve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319771/how-to-create-a-function-directly-from-the-output-of-solve)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x /. g[[1]]
```

Filler -> Thirty chars minimum

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a variable where to put the solve results? I tried `x ./ Solve[(x - 1) (x - 2) == 0, x]` but it failed...

Comment: @Andry `x /. Solve[(x - 1) (x - 2) == 0, x]`  ... you've the slash and the dot reversed

Comment: @Andry please read this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193 and all the other answers there, if possible

Comment: Tried this, still getting `v -> 2.05334*10^-7` in my new variable as opposed to just the number.

Comment: Tried andry's trick as well and now Mathermatica acts as though v is still unassigned (ie 2*v = `2v` rather than multiplying the number).

Comment: @Elliot I don't see any `v` here. Perhaps you mean `x`? If so, please try `x = x /. g[[1]]; Print@x`

Comment: I was speaking from my own program, not yours. The issue was the lack of `stuff =`. I thought the `/.` would assign on it's own.

Answer (score 12):

To complement Belisarius' answer,

```
x /. g
```

with `g = {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}}`, returns the list

```
{1, 2}
```

So to extract the first value, `1`, we could use

```
First[x /. g]
```

Other alternatives are

```
x /. g[[1]]
(x /. g)[[1]]    (* this is equivalent to the version using First *)
g[[1,1,2]]
```