# How to combine all solutions within one list in Mathematica?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

Using `Solve` function in Mathematica, we may get several solutions, e.g.

```
    In[1]:= Solve[x == 1 &&  2 >= y >= 1, {x, y}, Integers]
    Out[1]= {{x -> 1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 2}}
```

In case there are tens of solutions, the lists above will be messy.
Now I want to list only all possible values of x and y with a list like this

```
    {x->1, y->1,2}
```

Is there any easy way to reformat the output of the solution?

Another question, how to use the value from a solution?

```
    In[1]:= Solve[x == 1,{x}]
    Out[1]= {x -> 1}
    In[2]:= x
    Out[2]= x
    In[3]:= Definition[x]
    Out[3]= Null
    In[4]:= ?x
            Global`x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question you might use:

```
vars = {x, y};

sols = Solve[x == 1 && 2 >= y >= 1, vars, Integers];

Thread[ vars -> Union /@ (vars /. sols) ]
```

> ```
> {x -> {1}, y -> {1, 2}}
> ```

---

For your second question please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320155/618728).

Most handily:

```
sols = Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]

MapIndexed[(gg[#2[[1]]][a_] := #) &, x /. sols];
```

This makes assignments to the symbol `gg`.
The function is then used with the syntax `gg[1][17]` to mean the first solution, and `a == 17`:

```
Plot[gg[1][a], {a, 1, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
gg[2] /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {1/2 (-1 + I Sqrt[3]), -1, 1/2 (-3 + Sqrt[5])}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The lists follow the pattern of Mathematica rules, and therefore list replacement is the easiest way to get values from such lists.

Let's call the solution list `sol`:

```
In[3]:= sol = Solve[x == 1 && 2 >= y >= 1, {x, y}, Integers]
Out[3]= {{x -> 1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 2}}
```

Now take symbol `x`, and make the list of all replacements of `x` according to `sol` treated as a rule list:

```
In[4]:= x /. sol
Out[4]= {1, 1}
```

This immediately gives you an idea how to get all *distinct* values of `x` from all solutions:

```
In[5]:= Union[x /. sol]
Out[5]= {1}
```

Ditto for `y`, although all solutions are already distinct:

```
In[6]:= Union[y /. sol]
Out[6]= {1, 2}
```

Here's complete code from the above step-through for copying and pasting:

```
sol = Solve[x == 1 && 2 >= y >= 1, {x, y}, Integers]
x /. sol
Union[x /. sol]
Union[y /. sol]
Clear[sol]
```

Comment: There is a new [mathematica.se] only site, that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the rules returned by `Solve` into lists by using `ReplaceAll` or its short form `/.` as follows

```
Solve[x == 1 && 2 >= y >= 1, {x, y}, Integers] /.  Rule[a_, b_] -> b
```

This produces a list of lists: `{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}`. To get the results in the format you desire you can pass this list through a function that takes a pair `{a,b}` and returns `{x->a,y->b}`. A function like

```
  {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]} &
```

does does exactly this tranformation. Combining the two steps

```
 solutionlist = (Solve[x == 1 && 2 >= y >= 1, {x, y}, Integers] /. 
       Rule[a_, b_] -> b ) // {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]} &
```

produces

```
 {x -> {1, 1}, y -> {1, 2}}
```

for your example case.

To use the values from the solution, you can use

```
{xlist, ylist} = {x, y} /. solutionlist
```

Checking

```
 ?xlist
```

gives

[image: output for ?xlist]

EDIT: To delete duplicates change the function `{x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]} &` to

```
 {x -> Union@#[[1]], y -> Union@#[[2]]} &
```