# Mathematica - Plotting the output of a function created directly from solve

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I've got some fairly long matrix algebra that I am trying to plot the outcome of.  Nothing seems to show up on the axes, and I can't quite tell where the problem is.  I successfully created a function from the output of solve using the tips here:
[How to create a function directly from the output of Solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319771/how-to-create-a-function-directly-from-the-output-of-solve)
But it just won't plot!

Here (briefly) is the code:

`eqn = m.{1, r} == {t, 0}`

`sols1 = Solve[eqn, {t, r}]`

m is a complex matrix

Here is the output:

`{{t -> -((-1. cos[9.62458 s]^2 - (1. + 0. I) sin[9.62458 s]^2)/(
    cos[9.62458 s] - (0. + 2.4087 I) sin[9.62458 s])), 
  r -> ((0. + 2.1913 I) sin[9.62458 s])/(
   cos[9.62458 s] - (0. + 2.4087 I) sin[9.62458 s])}}`

So far so good (except that Mathematica seems to have trouble with the whole cos^2 + sin^2 = 1 thing).

Then I try to plot the real part of t as a function of s:

`Plot[Re[t /. sols1], {s, 0, 0.4}]`

And I just get empty axes.

I try assigning the output to a function and plotting that way

`f[s_] = t /. sols1[[1, 1]]`

`Plot[Re[f[s]], {s, 0, 0.4}]`

And I still get an empty axis.  I transcribed the function in Matlab where it plots just fine, so I know the solution is sound.  I have to solve this for several matrices m which just get hairier and hairier, so transcribing to Matlab is not ideal.  I want to plot right in Mathematica.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to capitalize `Sin` and `Cos`, then it will work.

Comment: @b.gatessucks THANK YOU!  Man, I feel like a dumbass. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using mathematica syntax. I.e. `Sin` in place of `sin`; same for `cos`:

```
In[1]:= sols1={
{t->-((-1. cos[9.62458 s]^2-(1.+0. I) sin[9.62458 s]^2)/(cos[9.62458 s]-(0.+2.4087 I) sin[9.62458 s]))
,r->((0.+2.1913 I) sin[9.62458 s])/(cos[9.62458 s]-(0.+2.4087 I) sin[9.62458 s])}
}/.{cos->Cos,sin->Sin}//FullSimplify//Chop
Out[1]= {{t->1./(Cos[9.62458 s]-(0. +2.4087 I) Sin[9.62458 s]),r->1/(-1.09921-(0. +0.45635 I) Cot[9.62458 s])}}
```

then e.g.

```
GraphicsColumn[Plot[t /. sols1 // #, {s, 0, .4}, PlotLabel -> #[t], Frame -> True] & /@ {Re, Im, Abs[#]^2 &}]
```

should work well.