# What is the difference between Set ( = ) and SetDelayed ( := )?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, assignment-operator

This discussion came up in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318942/force-function-evaluation-on-declaration) and I'm interested in knowing the difference between the two. Illustration with an example would be nice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Basic Example

Here is an example from Leonid Shifrin's book [Mathematica programming:  an advanced introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/Book.html)

It is an excellent resource for this kind of question.  See: [(1)](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node23.html) [(2)](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node171.html)

```
ClearAll[a, b]

a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];

b := RandomInteger[{1, 10}]
```

```
Table[a, {5}]
```

```
  {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
```

```
Table[b, {5}]
```

```
  {10, 5, 2, 1, 3}
```

---

### Complicated Example

The example above may give the impression that once a definition for a symbol is created using `Set`, its value is fixed, and does not change.  This is not so.

`f = ...` assigns to `f` an expression as it evaluates *at the time of assignment*.  If symbols remain in that evaluated expression, and later their values change, so does the apparent value of `f`.

```
ClearAll[f, x]

f = 2 x;
f
```

```
  2 x
```

```
x = 7;
f
```

```
  14
```

```
x = 3;
f
```

```
  6
```

It is useful to keep in mind how the rules are stored internally. For symbols assigned a value as `symbol = expression`, the rules are stored in `OwnValues`. Usually (but not always), `OwnValues` contains just one rule. In this particular case,

```
In[84]:= OwnValues[f]

Out[84]= {HoldPattern[f] :> 2 x}
```

The important part for us now is the r.h.s., which contains `x` as a symbol. What really matters for evaluation is this form - the way the rules are stored internally. As long as `x` did not have a value at the moment of assignment, both `Set` and `SetDelayed` produce (create) the same rule above in the global rule base, and that is all that matters. They are, therefore, equivalent in this context.

The end result is a symbol `f` that has a function-like behavior, since its computed value depends on the current value of `x`. This is not a true function however, since it does not have any parameters, and triggers only changes of the symbol `x`. Generally, the use of such constructs should be discouraged, since implicit dependencies on global symbols (variables) are just as bad in Mathematica as they are in other languages - they make the code harder to understand and bugs subtler and easier to overlook. Somewhat related discussion can be found [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node169.html).

---

### Set used for functions

`Set` can be used for functions, and sometimes it needs to be.  Let me give you an example.  Here Mathematica symbolically solves the Sum, and then assigns that to aF(x), which is then used for the plot.

```
ClearAll[aF, x]

aF[x_] = Sum[x^n Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}];

DiscretePlot[aF[x], {x, 1, 50}]
```

[image]

If on the other hand you try to use `SetDelayed` then you pass each value to be plotted to the `Sum` function.  Not only will this be much slower, but at least on Mathematica 7, it fails entirely.

```
ClearAll[aF, x]

aF[x_] := Sum[x^n Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}];

DiscretePlot[aF[x], {x, 1, 50}]
```

If one wants to make sure that possible global values for formal parameters (`x` here) do not interfere and are ignored during the process of defining a new function, an alternative to `Clear` is to wrap `Block` around the definition:

```
ClearAll[aF, x];
x = 1;
Block[{x}, aF[x_] = Sum[x^n Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]];
```

A look at the function's definition confirms that we get what we wanted:

```
?aF
Global`aF
aF[x_]=-(x/(-1+x+x^2))
```

Comment: It fails in M8 as well. Using `Evaluate` helps: `DiscretePlot[aF[x] // Evaluate, {x, 1, 50}]`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your Fibonacci-example. Surely `SetDelayed` is the correct choice here: the sum does not converge if x >= 1/GoldenRatio. So why woul `Set` be favorable here?

Comment: @JoMo It looks like it was just a stupid mistake.  Odd that nobody pointed it out for more than a decade.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

```
In[1]:= Attributes[Set]

Out[1]= {HoldFirst, Protected, SequenceHold}

In[2]:= Attributes[SetDelayed]

Out[2]= {HoldAll, Protected, SequenceHold}
```

As you can see by their attributes, both functions hold their first argument (the symbol to which you are assigning), but they differ in that SetDelayed also holds its second argument, while Set does not.  This means that Set will evaluate the expression to the right of `=` at the time the assignment is made.  SetDelayed does not evaluate the expression to the right of the `:=` until the variable is actually used.

What's happening is more clear if the right hand side of the assignment has a side effect (e.g. Print[]):

```
In[3]:= x = (Print["right hand side of Set"]; 3)
x
x
x

During evaluation of In[3]:= right hand side of Set

Out[3]= 3

Out[4]= 3

Out[5]= 3

Out[6]= 3

In[7]:= x := (Print["right hand side of SetDelayed"]; 3)
x
x
x

During evaluation of In[7]:= right hand side of SetDelayed

Out[8]= 3

During evaluation of In[7]:= right hand side of SetDelayed

Out[9]= 3

During evaluation of In[7]:= right hand side of SetDelayed

Out[10]= 3
```

Comment: +1 for the `x := (Print["right hand side of SetDelayed"]; 3)` construction. This type of thing is a handy debug technique to see when rules are firing.

Answer (score 3):

`:=` is for defining functions and `=` is for setting a value, basically.

ie `:=` will evaluate when its read, `=` will be evaluated when it is set.

think about:

```
x = 2
y = x
z := x
x = 4
```

Now, z is 4 if evaluated while y is still 2